# How to calculate inverse in chainlink tasks?

Tags: task, blockchain, inverse, chainlink, currency-exchange-rates

Hey I am trying to calculate inverse of a value that I got from an API call. I have my tasks like these.
[Tasks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1MTk.png)

```
parse        [type="jsonparse" path="quotes,USDEUR" data="$(fetch)"]
inverse      [type="divide" input="1" divisor="$(parse)" precision="5"]
multiply     [type="multiply" input="$(inverse)" times=1000000000000000000]
```

But I am getting the response like this.

[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTVRm.png)

**parse** jsonparse
1.022015

path: quotes,USDEUR

data: $(fetch)

**inverse** divide
"1"

input: 1

divisor: $(parse)

precision: 5

**multiply** multiply
"1000000000000000000"

input: $(inverse)

times: 1000000000000000000

What I need it to get inverse of the value getting from parse task. But when I do this I am just getting it as 1.